# Add additional behaviour to brush when using vertex paint mode

Tags: python, vertex-paint

I am using vertex paint mode to color my low poly mesh.

Additionally I need to set a metallic and a roughness value when the color is brushed on a vertex. The metallic and roughness values are stored in a RoughnessUVMap and a MetallicUVMap (so that they are exported via fbx and can easily read from a game engine).

How can I for example create my own brush via python and implement this behaviour?

Thanks!